# getting an error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Whenever I try to run my project, it runs perfectly but in the error pane it shows some kind of error.

I am using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

For now I have added the below lines into pom.xml as its a maven project -

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputencoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputencoding>
</properties>
```

But the problem is still there, adding sorceEncoding and reporting outputencoding into pom.xml did not resolves the problem. What is the problem?

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

**Update**

Error resolved after a soft restart but another error appears -

> Internal browser is not available: No more handles [Unknown Mozilla path (MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME not set)]

its something related to the browser and even my dashboard is prompting this.How can i resolve this?

Comment: @janos Yes sir its working now , error resolved . But another error came .. see my update.

Comment: Strange. A clean restart doesn't fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `project.build.sourceEncoding` to `UTF-8` like you did should work, but I think Eclipse cannot pick up this change from the pom automatically, you have to give it a gentle push: right-click on the project, and select **Maven / Update Project...** from the menu. That should fix it.

As a sanity check, you can compile the project using the command line, `mvn compile`, there shouldn't be a warning about the encoding.